# Asynchronous service calls using WebServiceTemplate

Tags: java, spring, web-services, asynchronous

I am using WebServiceTemplate to write the SOAP client for my application, but I found that it doesn't support sync service invocation.

I searched and found below post.
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/46527-spring-ws-client-and-jms-transport-for-asynchronous-service-calls

Do anyone have some workaround for this. Please suggest.

Thanks,